Suspenses don't behave as expected in NextJS
I observed a weird behavior in using suspense and key (or I misunderstood the loading behind the scene), Here is to preview in codesandbox feel free to fork and run
import { Suspense } from "react";
import MyButton from "./my-button";

async function ContainerOne() {
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
  return <div>Container 1</div>
}

async function ContainerTwo() {
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
  return <div>Container 2</div>
}

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Suspense key={Math.random()} fallback={<div>loading 1 ...</div>}>
        <ContainerOne />
      </Suspense>
      {/* <Suspense key={''} fallback={<div>loading 2 ...</div>}> */}
      <Suspense key={Math.random()} fallback={<div>loading 2 ...</div>}>
        <ContainerTwo />
      </Suspense>
      <MyButton />
    </div>
  );
}

if the key are both unique and random (or has changed), both components will behave normally with a loading fallback showing. However, if I changed the "ContainerTwo" key to a constant, let's say key={'b'}, the loading will become this -
"ContainerOne" wait "ContainerTwo" for 1s
"ContainerTwo" no loading (which is expected, since the key doesn't changed)
"ContainerOne" turn into loading for 2s
My expected behavior would be -
"ContainerOne" directly turn into loading for 3s
"ContainerTwo" no loading but data changed after 1s directly
My expected behavior would be - "ContainerOne" directly turn into loading for 3s "ContainerTwo" no loading but data changed after 1s directly

I think you are trying to use suspense in asynchronous way but in actual case the suspance is working in synchronous way. So, you need to use Lazy to achieve your output. Hope this helps.
import React, { Suspense, FC } from "react";
import MyButton from "./my-button";

const ContainerOne = React.lazy<FC>(
  () =>
    new Promise((resolve) =>
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Wait 1....");
        resolve({ default: () => <div>Container 1</div> });
      }, 3000)
    )
);

const ContainerTwo = React.lazy<FC>(
  () =>
    new Promise((resolve) =>
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Wait 2....");
        resolve({ default: () => <div>Container 2</div> });
      }, 1000)
    )
);

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>loading 1 ...</div>}>
        <ContainerOne />
      </Suspense>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>loading 2 ...</div>}>
        <ContainerTwo />
      </Suspense>
      <MyButton />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;

